# How to order layers with visgl/react-map-gl?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

How can I recreate this mapbox GLJS code with `visgl/react-map-gl`. I know they have beforeId prop to order the Layers but it is string. What if I need to pass more than one layer name? Thanks.

```
const glDraw = [ 'gl-draw-polygon-stroke-static.hot', 'gl-draw-line-static.hot', 'gl-draw-point-static.hot']
map.addLayer({
                    id: 'raster-tiles',
                    type: 'raster',
                    source: 'raster-tiles',
                }, ...glDraw)
```